# What is the best way to set far future expires on images with Django?

Tags: django

I am using django-compress with far future expires for my css and js files.  Works great.

I'd like to do something similar for other static content (images, flash, etc).  I can set a far future expires on this content, but I must manually rename the files when they change.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `django-compress`, you're treating CSS and JS as dynamic files - which is fine. However, the other files are static - and Django doesn't really want to serve these. They should be served directly by Apache or other webserver.

With Apache, you'd put something like

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

in `.htaccess` or the global Apache configuration.

**Update:** Responding to your comment - Sorry I didn't understand the nuance of your question. There isn't much you can do to avoid using a different URL to indicate to a client that a file (e.g. an image) has changed. This is recommended by e.g. Apache and YAHOO!

Implementing this is IMO not too hard. It's in two parts:

1. Use a tag (here's a [useful snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/666/)) to generate versioned URLs to media files which will appear in your HTML. The versioned URL could be the base URL with the version inserted, e.g. `/media/3/header.png` where the actual file remains as `/media/header.png` on the server.
2. Use a tool like `mod_rewrite` to convert incoming URLs to the canonical value, i.e. a request for `/media/3/header.png` gets converted to `/media/header.png`. [This article](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-fix-for-caching-updated-files.html) describes the feature in more detail.

Comment: I know how to set the far future expires on images, but I was wondering if there is a better way to handle when I edit an image.  Say I have header.png with far future expires.  I then edit it in photoshop.  I would have to name it to header1.png and then change any references in the code to header1.png.  Not ideal for me.

Answer (score 6):

The best way would be to refer to your static files with a versioned URL, and give your web server a rewrite rule to ignore the version.

See a complete Django example [here](http://www.django-hosting.de/wiki/MediaFileExpire/), which includes an `expire_tag` helper (created by [Arne Brodowski](http://www.arnebrodowski.de/blog/)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{% expire_tag "css/reset.css" %}" />
```

And the relevant Apache rewrite rules.

Comment: Now that is pretty slick.  I'll have to remember that one.

Comment: Nice, minor downside is that this approach does not version images referred to inside css.